# Add disable class to span if checkbox is disabled using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

I have this checkbox code

```
<div class="checkbox-group">

    <label class="fc-contain-sm checkbox-status">
        <input type="checkbox" class="formjs-checkbox-sm" checked disabled>
        <div class="fc-status-sm"></div>
        <span class="checkbox-lable-sm">Disabled checkbox</span>
    </label>

    <label class="fc-contain-sm checkbox-status">
        <input type="checkbox" class="formjs-checkbox-sm">
        <div class="fc-status-sm"></div>
        <span class="checkbox-lable-sm">Normal checkbox</span>
    </label>

</div>
```

And i want to add class `disabled` to `checkbox-lable-sm` class if the checkbox is disabled using jquery

css

```
.checkbox-group .disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

I have tried this code but it is not working

```
$('.checkbox-group > input:disabled.formjs-checkbox-sm').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.checkbox-lable-sm').addBack().addClass("disabled");
});
```

Comment: I'm confused, you say "Add class for label" but your code shows your trying to add it to the `span` ?

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try to this,

```
$(".checkbox-group input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':disabled')) {
    $(this).closest(".fc-contain-sm").find(".checkbox-lable-sm").addClass("disabled");
  }
});
```

I am sure this will work.

Here is working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3p2gb7p/10/)

Here is second way,

```
$(".checkbox-group input[type='checkbox']:disabled").each(function() {
  $(this).closest(".fc-contain-sm").find(".checkbox-lable-sm").addClass("disabled");
});
```

Here is third way,

```
$(".checkbox-group input[type='checkbox']:disabled").each(function() {
  $(this).closest("label").find(".checkbox-lable-sm").addClass("disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.checkbox-group input:disabled.formjs-checkbox-sm').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.checkbox-lable-sm').addClass("disabled");
});
```